# Display toast message on record update in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to display error message when a particular field is changed on case record page in lightning (this is standard page and not a custom lightning component) and user clicks on save.

Error message needs to have multiple lines and hence cannot be achieved using `addError(error message,escape);` as lightning does not support `HTML` tags.(I have already this option and it didn't work). I cannot use `validation rule` since logic behind displaying error message is a complex one.

Is it possible to handle any events on standard case page layout that gets fired on when user clicks save button and then compare on old and new value of an edited field and then perform a server call, so that I can display a message/toast and interrupt the `DML` execution.

Comment: No. You're going to have to deal with not having line breaks.